# Microphones, Loudspeaker and their analogies to spring mass system

Tags: specific-reference, classical-mechanics, electric-circuits, acoustics, linear-systems

I have just started studying Microphones and Loudspeakers. I need a good text to refer which can explain their mechanical analogies with simplicity and basics too.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find it, this one is good:  [Introduction to Electroacoustics and Audio Amplifier Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0757503756) by W. M Leach.

Keep in mind that microphones and loudspeakers *are* (electroacoustic) mechanical systems.  For example, the cone has mass and the surround provides a restoring force.

In the book I linked to, an *electrical* analogy of the mechanical system (and of the acoustic system too) is made and simulated in SPICE.